# Go package import issue

Tags: go

I've my folder setup like this:

```
-src
--bitbucket.org
---eagleamulet
----myFirst.go (package main)
-----utils
------tempconv
-------tempconv.go (package tempconv)
```

However I'm not able to add the tempconv package to myFirst.go My Go environment settings look ok, so I'm not sure what's wrong here:

[temppackage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYXkk.png)

[goenv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfBn0.png)

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

thanks
EA

Comment: What is the error message reported by the go tool?  Is the absolute path of the `src` directory `/Users/sunitjoshi/Projects/go/src`?

Comment: Here it is:○ → go install myFirst.go 
# command-line-arguments
./myFirst.go:35: undefined: BoilC
./myFirst.go:35: undefined: FreezC
./myFirst.go:36: undefined: CelToFar
./myFirst.go:36: undefined: BoilC
./myFirst.go:38: undefined: Far
./myFirst.go:39: undefined: Cel
./myFirst.go:40: undefined: FarToCel

Comment: My bad, I forgot to qualify the function name with the package...Duuh. Once I used that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Keep forgetting about qualifying the function names. It would have worked if I had done **.** to import into the current namespace.

Answer (score 1):

All the packages imported are looked in under GOROOT and GOPATH environment variables first. Make sure your package is somewhere under these directories.

Now Suppose **GOPATH** is set to : /Users/test/Desktop/GoProject/src(lets assume, your src directory)

and *GOROOT* : /usr/local/go (where go is installed)
. If a file(myFirst.go) in your GoProject has a package imported as

```
import "abc/def/packageName"
```

then it should be present at any of the below two places:

**/Users/test/Desktop/GoProject**/src/abc/def/packageName/*
*/usr/local/go*/src/abc/def/packageName/*

If not, you will get import error.

The files inside these directories will have the first line as

```
package packageName
```

stating that all these files constitutes a package **packageName**